# Coin toss simulation

Tags: matlab

```
clear all
%heads>=0.5 %tails<0.5
for i=1:500
    coin=rand(1,2);     
    A=[coin];
    toss=1;
while coin(1)<.5
    coin=rand(1,2);
    B=[coin];
    toss=1+tossr;
    A=[A;B];
    C=[toss];
end
fprintf('Number of toss to obtain head  %.0f \n',toss)
end
```

How can I make vector of frequency of all toss?

I want to make a frequency table of all the tosses

[image]

Comment: If you need 500 tosses, why not just generate a random vector of size 500?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soltion using `randi`

```
clearvars
toss=0;

for i=1:500
    if randi(2)==1 %1 for tails, 2 for heads
        toss=toss+1;
    else
        FreqToss(i)=toss;
        fprintf('Number of toss to obtain head  %.0f \n',toss)
        toss=0;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this is a simpler solution:

```
clear; clc; close;
toss=0;
Tossvector=[];

%heads>=0.5 %tails<0.5
for i=1:500
    coin=rand();     
    if coin <.5
        toss=toss+1;
        Tossvector=horzcat(Tossvector,toss);
    end
    if coin >.5
        fprintf('Number of toss to obtain head  %.0f \n',toss)
        toss=0;
    end
end
```